# Do I need a GFI Breaker if there are lights on the circuit prior to an outlet?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Our home has no grounding run throughout it an 2 prong outlets currently except for GFI outlets in bathrooms, kitchen, basement. I am currently installing GFI outlets in the first outlets in the circuit but one of my circuits has the basement light on the circuit prior to the first outlet. Do I need to install a GFI breaker for this circuit or will putting a GFI outlet in the first outlet be up to code with the light prior to the GFI outlet.

Answer (score 2):

Lights and fans do not need GFCI protection unless they are

- In a tub or shower stall
- using **receptacles**, e.g. the classic 4' fluorescents plugged into sockets on the ceiling in a garage, **and also** in a space where receptacles require GFCI (garage, basement, laundry etc.)  For instance a plug-in wall sconce in a bedroom or plug-in pendant in a tall living room does not need GFCI.

Note that GFCIs on the ceiling are not permitted, because "test monthly" is not realistic. For such lights you need GFCI elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, so it’s not an issue to have a hardwired light on the circuit prior to the first outlet on the circuit which is a gfci outlet? I had put a gfci outlet first on another circuit and was using an outlet tester which showed correct wiring. Now with this circuit the gfci it is showing “open ground” but the only thing upstream of the gfci is a hardwired light. The rest of the outlets also shut off when hitting test on the gfci.

Comment: @bigoljamie yeah, having always-hot for a hardwired light tapped off upstream of a GFCI outlet is no big deal at all

Comment: @bigoljamie Harper is assuming that you are not replacing the basement light as part of this project.  That's what makes it allowable.  Reference NEC 410.44.

Comment: @bigoljamie It sounds like you are using a 3-light tester. Rule #1 If the red light is lit, the label is wrong - do not follow its instructions!  #2  when you're pushing the button, *ignore the lights* as they are wrong (that's normal).  #3 if "open ground" is reported, that means the GFCI test button will not work, and that's normal/OK/expected. It does not indicate a GFCI problem.